# XPath: how to select only part of the node text as a WebElement

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenide

I have HTML like this:

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="tCell">Feb 2018</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Here is XPath which returns me `WebElement` (`SelenideElement` in Selenide or `Node` in browser debugger): `.//*[@id='tCell']`
Here is XPath which returns me the String with `Feb`: `substring-before(.//*[@id='tCell'], ' ')`

My problem is that I need to receive the same `Feb` value, but as a Node.

Does someone have any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities to get this certain `td` node:

Globally:

```
//td[@id='tCell']
```

And specifically:

```
/html/table/tr/td[@id='tCell']
```

Both do get the element node which `text()` sub-node has the content "Feb 2018".

Comment: Thank you for answer. The same thing I wrote in my question that I have already know how to receive especially this node. But I'm trying to get only part of text as a node. that's the point.

Comment: @0xFF: Sorry if I had misunderstood your question. But you cannot retrieve a substring as a node. That's simply impossible. You can only get it as a value (like: "Feb").